# fullCalendar - include end date

Tags: mysql, fullcalendar

I'm working on a events cms and using fullCalendar.io to show the events.
My events are only dates without time and I'm storing the informations in a mySQL database.
I have no way to change the mySQL column format nor the event insertion method to add a time to the date, although I need to show the end date included while showing the calendar.
I'll paste my code to show how it works.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({           
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next,today',
        center: 'title'
    },
    defaultView: 'month', 
    eventSources: [{
        url: 'getJsonEvents',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
        },
        error: function() {
        },
        color: '#2D4047',
        textColor: 'white',
    }]
});
```

the column that store the date is a simple DATE mysql column.

EDIT:
To be clear, the problem is that my event end (eg.) the 19th but on the calendar view it seems to end the 18th.

[Attached image](http://prntscr.com/fg4s5r)

Comment: so what exactly is your question? It's not clear what your issue is or what you want to achieve. You've shown your code (which looks incomplete, BTW) but not said what doesn't work.

Comment: As I said, I need to show the end date INCLUDED in the calendar view, which currently is not (EG: my event start July the 16th and end July the 19th, but on the calendar the event seems to end the 18th) Attached image: http://prntscr.com/fg4s5r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ :

> "end"...is the moment immediately *after* the event has ended. For
>   example, if the last full day of an event is **Thursday**, the exclusive
>   end of the event will be 00:00:00 on **Friday**!

So if you have an all-day event you simply need to increase the value of the "end" parameter you're sending to fullCalendar by 1 day. This is a pretty common approach - Google Calendar's API does it the same way, for example.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, the problem is that I fetch the list of events from an url. Is there a way to change the end date before rendering the calendar?

Comment: Absolutely. Your "eventSources" code in your sample is incomplete, but it looks like you're already broadly following the approach shown here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/. Within that function you can do anything you like to the event data before you send it on to fullCalendar. In that example it creates a whole new object for each event. You don't need to go that far, but you could simply modify the "end" property of each all-day event. This callback: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/ also allows you do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Again @ADyson, can you show me how to mark the answer as correct? Sorry but I'm new to posting on StackOverflow. :)

Comment: But when you add 1 day, you need to subtract it again, when e.g. displaying or editing the date itself

Comment: @Armin Maybe, it depends how you want your UI to work, I guess. But it doesn't remove the fact that this is the way it works. You can't avoid it.

Comment: Yes. I've stored the real end date in an extendedProp and use this for output. Thx :)

Answer (score -1):

Add 9 hr in end date then it will consider in calender

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).